# Android connected tests common code move to library module

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have 2 project modules: A, B and a library module. Both projects using a library. I also have some connected tests in both projects (UI Automator). That tests have common utility code that I'd like to move to the library. How can I do it?

What I've tried. First way:

1. Copy common code to library project to src/androidTest/java/xxx
   folder
2. Add to library build.gradle UI automator dependencies under
   androidTestCompile
3. Add to project build.gradle following:

---

```
dependecies {
...
androidTestCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: "debug")
...
}
```

That cause build issue in project because as I understand src/androidTest folder is not used during building debug configuration

Second way:

1. First 2 steps are same
2. Add to library build.gradle

---

```
task connectedTestsJars(type: Jar, dependsOn: "assembleXXXAndroidTest") {
    classifier = 'connectedTests'
    includes = ['com/**']
    from "$buildDir/intermediates/classes/androidTest/XXX"
}

configurations {
    connectedTestArtifact
}

artifacts {
    connectedTestArtifact connectedTestsJars
}
```

3. Add to project build.gradle

---

```
dependencies {
...
androidTestCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: "connectedTestArtifact")
...
}
```

That way all compiles fine. It crashes during connected test runtime because of missing resources from library (it has a lot of common code and resources from both projects)
As I understand that happens because I am using only sources from the library, but I need to use aar file instead (aar with adding src/androidTest contents?).
What will be task type in that case? Or what actions I should make in my custom task to get aar file as result? Other way?

I understand that I can move connected tests common code to another (second) library module and use, but I'd like to avoid it to save compilation time. 
Is there any way to keep current module structure and move connected tests common code to library module?

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution. Add to project's build.gradle:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['../<LIBRARY_MODULE_NAME>/src/androidTest/java', 'src/androidTest/java']
        }
    }
...
}
```

I am sure there is a better solution since the common code will be compilated in both projects. Who knows it?